# How to access the address data from Python QBO API wrapper Sidecars?

Tags: python, api, quickbooks-online

I am getting a "TypeError: 'Address' object is not subscriptable" error when using the Quickbooks Online API wrapper Sidecars [here](https://github.com/sidecars/python-quickbooks) to access my company data file address.  I can access the whole lot by:

```
print(customer.BillAddr)
```

But I need just the post code and city.  If I do a:

```
dir(customer.BillAddr)
```

I get the following returned which shows City and PostalCode:

> ['City', 'Country', 'CountrySubDivisionCode', 'Id', 'Lat', 'Line1',
>   'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4', 'Line5', 'Long', 'Note', 'PostalCode',
>   '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
>   '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**',
>   '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**',
>   '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**',
>   '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
>   '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', 'class_dict', 'detail_dict',
>   'from_json', 'json_filter', 'list_dict', 'to_dict', 'to_json']

But I have tried:

```
customer.BillAddr['PostalCode']
```

And it simply says:

> TypeError: 'Address' object is not subscriptable

How can I access the specific fields?

Comment: have you tried `custumer.BillAddr.PostalCode` ?

Comment: I have and it gave a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PostalCode'" error.  That was actually the first thing I thought of but thank you.